# Why is Jersey not seeing my new endpoint method?

Tags: spring, jersey, jax-rs

I have a SpringBoot/JAX-RS service that has been working fine for a while.  I'm trying to add a temporary endpoint method to one resource class with existing endpoint methods.  For some reason, Jersey is not registering the method, which results in a 404 when I try to curl the url.

I've tried to do some obvious things:

- I implemented an `ApplicationEventListener` that looks at the final `ResourceModel` after the `INITIALIZATION_APP_FINISHED` event is processed.
- I commented out one of the existing endpoint methods to verify it was even processing that class.

I ran the service in the debugger so I can inspect the ResourceModel.  It shows all of the defined endpoint methods in the resource class, except for the new one that I've added, and if I comment out one of the existing resource methods, that one also goes away from the ResourceModel.  It seems like it just doesn't like my new method declaration, but I have no idea why.

This is my method declaration:

```
@GET
@Path("/fakestatus")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Changes the fake health indicator status.",
        notes = "Changes the fake health indicator status.",
        response = Response.class)
public Response changeFakeHealthIndicatorStatus(@QueryParam("status") String status,
                                                @Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

I didn't used to have the `ApiOperation`, `Consumes`, `Produces`, or `Context` parameters. I added those incrementally to see if any of those made a difference.  Those are similar to other methods in the service and other similar services.

The interface declaration starts with this:

```
@Api("note")
@Path("/notes")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public interface NoteResource {
```

**Update**:

I have managed to resolve this, but I'm not sure what exactly is happening here.

The problem wasn't in the interface, it was in the implementation class.

I originally had this in the implementation class:

```
@Override
public Response changeFakeHealthIndicatorStatus(@QueryParam("status") String status) {
    fakeHealthIndicator.setStatus(status);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("Status").build();
}
```

The key is the `@QueryParam` annotation.  I had just cut/pasted the method signature from the interface.  I had thought that the annotation probably would be ignored here, but that was my mistake.  Removing that fixes the problem.

I'm not sure exactly what is happening here, but it seems like the code that examines this hierarchy to create resource mappings ends up finding the "deepest" method because of that annotation being present, but when it looks for other annotations on the method, like "@GET" or "@Path", those are not on that method, but on the interface method.

By removing what I thought was an ignored annotation, it ends up finding it in the base class, where all the required annotations were present.

Comment: It's in the JAX-RS spec. If you put any JAX-RS annotations on the implementation method, all other interface annotations are ignored (this includes the @Path, which is what defines it as an endpoint)

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks for that, good to have documentation for the behavior that I determined.